# Django: Returning a queryset that has non overlapping values in 2 models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models:

```
Pages
------------
Page    User
S500    John
Gimp    John
WoW     John

Subscriptions
------------
Page    User 
S500    John
```

So Page field in Subs model is an FK to Pages model. I am trying to return a queryset that will display all the pages belonging to John that **doesn't** have a subscription belonging to him.

I tried something like:

```
fbpages = Page.objects.filter(user='John').exclude(id__in=[Page.id for Page in Page.subscriptions.filter(Page=Page)])
```

I think I'm close but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with that query.

I did something like:

```
current_subs = Subscriptions.objects.filter(user='John')
pages = Page.objects.filter(user='John').exclude(id__in=[subs.Page.id for subs in current_subs])
```

which works but how do I combine it into 1 query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(user='John').exclude(subscriptions__user="John")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a little more directly by using the reverse direction of your foreign key. If you haven't set `reverse_name`, I think this should look like

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(user='John').filter(subscriptions_set=None)
```